# How can I compile .NET 3.5 C# code on a system without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have some C# code that uses some constructs specific to .NET 3.5. When you install the .NET Framework distribution, you get the C# compiler installed with it (csc.exe). Even if I specify the csc.exe in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5, I cannot compile the code on a computer with **only** the .NET Framework installed, but not Visual Studio. I am able to compile code that uses v2.0 constructs without difficulty. How can I accomplish this?

Here is a sample that demonstrates my problem:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // The MacOSX value to the PlatformID enum was added after
        // .NET v2.0
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.MacOSX)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found mac");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Simple program");
    }
}
```

When compiling this code using csc.exe, I receive the following error:

test.cs(9, 58): error CS0117: 'System.PlatformID' does not contain a definition for 'MacOSX'

When executing `csc.exe /?` I receive the banner:

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler version 3.5.21022.8
>   for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 3.5
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: It should be fine to compile things without Visual Studio. Could you give an example of what you're trying to compile and what errors you're getting? Without that information we're working blind...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could expand on "I cannot compile the code on a computer with **only** the .NET Framework installed", what errors does csc return?

Comment: What is the version when you just type csc.exe ?  Is it showing a 3.5.* version of the compiler or 2.0?

Comment: As a side note, if can't install VisualStudio because it's expensive but you can install an IDE, have a look at: [SharpDevelop](http://www.sharpdevelop.net/opensource/sd/)

Comment: @digEmAll, or indeed Visual Studio Express! =)

Comment: @JimEvans, does using MSBuild (as per my answer) generate the same error? (If you actually have a solution/project, that is)

Comment: Possibly a silly question but what results do you get if you compile with the switch `/langversion:3`?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, of course :). I don't know why, but I don't like the express version very much...

Comment: Do you have 3.5 SP1 installed? I can compile your example code with the following framework version: `Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler version 3.5.30729.4926`.

Comment: Lack of SP1 was the problem. Silly me, I thought the service pack had been slipstreamed into the main download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler version 3.5.21022.8

That's old, original .NET 3.5 release.  Service Pack 1 has a rather unfortunate name, there were a great many changes.  I don't have the time machine to check if it added the MacOSX member.  Timing is about right for coinciding with Silverlight.

Enable Windows Update or install SP1 directly.

Comment: According to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a8hyw88(v=vs.90).aspx PlatformID.MacOSX was added in 3.5 SP1

Comment: Yup, David Kean's annotation is the slam dunk.  He's a reliable source.

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding your error:**

> The PlatformId.Xbox and
>   PlatformId.MaxOSX values were
>   introduced in .NET Framework 2.0 SP2,
>   3.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1.

That is probably why you cannont compile your example using the command line. When having SP1 installed your version number for 3.5 SP 1 should look like this:

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler version 3.5.30729.4926

There's a whole section on MSDN about [Command-Line building](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

> If you are working on a computer that
>   only has the .NET Framework SDK, you
>   can use the C# compiler at the command
>   line if you use the SDK Command
>   Prompt, which is available from the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework SDK menu
>   option.

It also states what happens if you have multiple versions of .NET Framework installed:

> The csc.exe executable is usually
>   located in the
>   Microsoft.NET\Framework\
>   folder under the system directory. Its
>   location may vary depending on the
>   exact configuration on any individual
>   computer. Multiple versions of this
>   executable will be present on the
>   computer if more than one version of
>   the .NET Framework is installed on the
>   computer. For more information about
>   such installations, see [Determining
>   Which Version of the .NET Framework Is
>   Installed.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y549e41e.aspx)

**Example**

`csc File.cs`

In my case I can do:

`cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>`

`csc somefile.cs`

This should output something like this:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>csc
>
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights  reserved.

Comment: @Filip, there won't be a `VSVARS32.BAT` on a machine where Visual Studio isn't installed, as the OP has indicated is the case

Comment: I've updated my answer. Does it still not answer to his problem and deserves down-votes?

Comment: The problem is not that I need a tutorial on how to build from the command line using csc.exe. I'm well aware of how to do this. Your original answer (before you edited it) gave me no information that I didn't already have.

Comment: @JimEvans, After you provided more information about your actual problem. I edited my answer and gave you a correct answer to why it wasn't working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)? =)

Visual Studio project files are (under the hood) MSBuild files, and it can also [transform solution files](http://www.dioramadesign.net/blog/msbuild-and-solution-files/) into MSBuild files, effectively meaning that you can use MSBuild from the command line to build a Visual Studio solution.

For example, say I have a project located in `C:\Repositories\Work\MyProject\` with an associated solution file of `MyProject.sln` and I can do the following at a command line:

> **C:\Users\Me\>** CD\
>   **C:\>** CD Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
>   **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\>** MSBuild /p:Configuration=debug

MSBuild will then build any projects in that solution that are set to build for the `debug` configuration, and output something similar to the following:

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version
>   3.5.30729.4926 [Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.4952]
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation
>   2007. All rights reserved.
>
> Build started 17/02/2011 14:55:49.
>   Project
>   "c:\repositories\work\MyProject\MyProject.sln"
>   on node 0 (default  targets).
>   Building solution configuration
>   "Debug|.NET". Project
>   "c:\repositories\work\MyProject\MyProject.sln"
>   (1) is building "c
>   :\repositories\work\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.csproj"
>   (2) on node 0 (default targets).
>   Processing 0 EDMX files.   Finished
>   processing 0 EDMX files. CoreCompile:
>   Skipping target "CoreCompile" because
>   all output files are up-to-date with
>   resp ect to the input files.
>   CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:   Copying
>   file from "obj\Debug\MyProject.dll" to
>   "bin\MyProject.dll".   MyProject ->
>   c:\repositories\work\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Ultra.Clie
>   nt.dll   Copying file from
>   "obj\Debug\MyProject.pdb" to
>   "bin\MyProject.pdb". Done Building
>   Project
>   "c:\repositories\work\MyProject\MyProject\Ultra.Cli
>   ent.csproj" (default targets).
>
> Ultra_Client_Setup:   The project
>   "MyProject.Setup" is not selected for
>   building in solution con   figuration
>   "Debug|.NET". Done Building Project
>   "c:\repositories\work\MyProject\MyProject.sln"
>   (def ault targets).
>
> Build succeeded.
>       0 Warning(s)
>       0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.92

*Caveat*: MSBuild isn't capable of processing setup projects

Comment: +1, good solution. I recently needed to build a DLL programmatically; I used MSBuild to do it, and it works even on a machine that doesn't have the .NET SDK installed

Comment: @Thomas, yeup - MSBuild is an unsung hero that makes life a *lot* easier for a lot of things, I wish there was more awareness of it!

Comment: MSBuild is also covered in the link I posted about command line building.

Comment: MSBuild, while a great tool, is not appropriate for the environment I'm working in. The build system of the project is such that calling csc directly is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you have an environment variable that points to the wrong version of the framework